# How to open new project on Redmine?

Tags: redmine

How is it that on my "Projects" page on Redmine, even once connected, there's no "New Project" link anywhere to be found? 
Contrary to the demo version.

[My account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JU0hq.png)
[Their demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1iwq.png)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Redmine has fine-grained, role-based permission system. Permissions are managed on global and per-project level, even per-field and per-status, based on workflow...

You don't see new project button, because you are not administrator, nor you have any role on some project which can grant you that permission.

You should contact your administrator or project manager to elevate your role.

Comment: Thank you for answering me.

What about if this project does not exist yet ? I'll need to promote myself administrator on my own not-existing-yet project ^^'
I want to open a fresh project, on which I'll be an administrator. How can I do that?
How can I do if the project does not exist yet, and I just want to begin one ?

Comment: Someone has to be administrator, once you install redmine, you must configure admin account first. Then anything else.